# How to disable the junk mail filter in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird through Firefox and I would like to disable the junk folder completely. A lot of my mail goes to junk folder and I don’t want it there. I have tried all suggestions given in this article to no avail.

How do I eliminate junk folder so that *no* mail is considered junk? I would rather go through all garbage mail and not miss important mail as I have done in past because it went to junk.

Comment: “I have tried all suggestions given in this article to no avail.” What article?

Comment: *"I am using Thunderbird through Firefox"* - What does this mean? Are your referencing an extension such as [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/thunderbird-online-email/)?